# Use function on Jade output on client side?

Tags: parsing, node.js, client-side, express, pug

I want to parse tweets with this function with content served via Node.js/Express/Jade client side.

```
String.prototype.parseHashtag = function() {
    return this.replace(/[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g, function(t) {
        var tag = t.replace("#","%23")
        return t.link("http://search.twitter.com/search?q="+tag);
    });
};
```

I would like to do it client side so that for example when a new tweet is added that can be parsed to with the same code and displayed directly and not have to go back and forth to the backend and be parsed.

I've made it work with this code, but is there any way to make it simpler, prettier?

```
!= "<script type='text/javascript'>"
!= "var body = '"
= contents[c].body
!= "';"
!= "document.write(body.parseHashtag());"
!= "</script>"
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. I will suggest you the following way:

```
script(type='text/javascript') 
    var body = contents[c].body;
    document.write(body.parseHashtag());
```

you should also see jade documentation for it:[enter link description here](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade)

Comment: For me the contents[c].body don't get written by Jade doing it this way. It just treats it like a client side javascript variable.